# Can I watch less files change and convert it to css files by webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

In my project, I want to watch all my `*.less` file change, and convert it to `*.css`. I used `gulp` to do this before. Is it possible to do it with `webpack` ?

I found that if I didn't import `less` file, it can't be found by `webpack`, so I am stuck with this problem.

There is my directory, I want to convert `src/**/*.less` to `dist/**/*.css`:

```
|-- src 
    |-- a.less
    |-- b.less
    |-- order
        |-- c.less


|-- dist
     |-- a.css
     |-- b.css
     |-- order
         |-- c.css
```

There is my `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: "./src",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 200,
    poll: 1000,
    ignored: /node_modules/
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: 'less-loader',
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use. [lessloader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader)
and in webpack config filed define the rules to load the less loader as below :

In case you need to pick the files from specific directory, you can define the directory path using `include` option.

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: 
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                    { 
                      loader: 'less-loader',
                      include: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/styles'),
                     ]
                   }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this way I still can't detect changes in less files, I will not import less in my JS file or HTML file, I just want change Less file :(

Comment: you got to import ur less file in your main js file so that less-loader pick it and convert to to css.

Comment: This method is unrealistic for me. Due to the particularity of the project, I cannot use the `import`  method, and I can only convert less.

Comment: you can define the directory path. in loader itslef form where you want. to pick the files and conert to css in case you dont want to import file ```include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/styles')
        ]``` as i. mentioned in the answer